# При обновлении не работает окно

Tags: jquery

При обновлении страницы (тоесть нажатие в браузере на кнопку) не открывается окно, а если перезайти на ссылку то работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#window').hide();
    alert("helo1");
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
  });

  $('#url').click(function() {
    $('#window').fadeIn(100);
    alert("helo2");
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

  });

});
```

```css
div{
  display:block;
}

.container{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container" id="window">
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="url" value="url"/>
    <input type="button" id="close" value="Close"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#close').click(function() {
        $('#window').hide();
        document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
    });

    $('#url').click(function() {
        $('#window').fadeIn(100);
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    });

    $('#window').fadeIn(100);

});
```

Comment: Если бы всё было в вызове показа блока, то тогда бы он ни при перезагрузке, ни при прямом входе не показывался, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Исходя из данных которые есть. Показывается при клике на кнопку, не показывается при загрузке страницы. Вызова при загрузке нет, значит дела в этом. Могут быть разные причины, но информации иной нет.

Comment: я «перезайти на ссылку» понимаю как прямой переход на страницу. Надеюсь, правда за вами=)

Comment: я «перезайти на ссылку» воспринял как - "клик по ссылке". Правда за автором)